# Date format in javascript :- Date.parse()

Tags: javascript, date

Which format does java script support and why :-

I used :

`Date.parse (23/01/2015)` - It shows NAN
`Date.parse (11/01/2015)` - gives certain value.

My application have date format :- day/month/year. 
How to parse in this format.

Comment: hope this is useful http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: _Which format does java script support._ Just read the *** [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `Date.parse` is not what you were looking for. It returns a timestamp integer value.
You want `new Date(string)` constructor, which builds a `Date` JavaScript object:

```js
document.body.innerText = new Date('01/01/2016').toString();
```

However, JavaScript does work with `mm/dd/yyyy` format by default.
For parsing `dd/mm/yyyy` you will have to implement your own parser using [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and `new Date(year, zeroBasedMonth, day)` constructor:

```js
function parseDdmmyyyy(str)
{
  var parts = str.split('/');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]); 
}

document.body.innerText = parseDdmmyyyy('24/11/2015');
```

Answer (score 2):

`Date.parse` need a string parameter:

```
Date.parse("11/01/2015")
```

This line give you a [TimeStamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

But to get a valid date you need to pass the format `MM-DD-YYYY`

So split the string and transform the format like :

```
var date = "11/01/2015".split("/");
var goodDate = date[1] + "-" + date[0] + "-" + date[2]
```

After you can use the `Date` object like :

```
var obDate = new Date.parse(goodDate);
```

With the object, you can get the month/day/year separately :

```
var day = obDate.getDate(); // Get the day 
var month = obDate.getMonth() + 1; // The month start to zero
var year = obDate.getFullYear();// Get the year 

console.log( day + "/" + month + "/" year );
```